# How to create a summary data table based on counts?

Tags: r

I want to calculate the sum of one column using data from another column. Essentially, I am looking to see if student ethnicity influences drawing ethnicity by observing how frequently a student of a certain ethnicity tends to different ethnicities.

I have a `dataframe` that currently looks like this:

| Student_Ethnicity | Drawing_Ethnicity |
| --- | --- |
| White | White |
| Black | Asian |
| White | Black |
| Asian | No Selection |
| Black | Asian |

But I want it to look like this:

| Student_Ethnicity | White | Black | Asian | No Selection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| White | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Black | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| Asian | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

It is important that the data is summed in each column and that the Student Ethnicity column is collapsed into one of each ethnicity.

Here is some reproducible code:

```
df <- structure(list('Student_Ethnicity' = c("White", "Black", "White", "Asian", "Black"), 
                 'Drawing_Ethnicity' = c("White", "Asian", "Black", "No Selection", "Asian")), 
            row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Edit:** please find below a larger version of the dataset:

```r
structure(list(Predict_DAS.Student_Ethnicity = c("White/Caucasian", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Other", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Multiple", "White/Caucasian", 
"White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", 
"White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Other", "Other", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "Hispanic/Latinx", "Other", "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander", 
"Black/African American", "Black/African American", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Other", "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Other", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "American Indian or Alaskan Native", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "White/Caucasian", "Hispanic/Latinx", "Black/African American", 
"American Indian or Alaskan Native", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Multiple", "White/Caucasian", "American Indian or Alaskan Native", 
"No Selection", "Asian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander", "Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "American Indian or Alaskan Native", "No Selection", 
"Asian", "Black/African American", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "American Indian or Alaskan Native", 
"Black/African American", "Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "Black/African American", "Multiple", 
"White/Caucasian", "Hispanic/Latinx", "White/Caucasian", "Asian", 
"Multiple", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Multiple", "Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "Other", "Black/African American", 
"Multiple", "Black/African American", "Hispanic/Latinx", "White/Caucasian", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "Hispanic/Latinx", "Multiple", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "Asian", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "Other", "Multiple", "Multiple", "Multiple", 
"No Selection", "Asian", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "Other", "White/Caucasian", "American Indian or Alaskan Native", 
"White/Caucasian", "Hispanic/Latinx", "Multiple", "Hispanic/Latinx"
), Predict_DAS.PreDAS_Ethnicity = c("White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Asian", "White/Caucasian", "Other", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "No Selection", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"Black/African American", "No Selection", "Asian", "Other", "No Selection", 
"No Selection", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "No Selection", 
"No Selection", "Hispanic/Latinx", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "Black/African American", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Hispanic/Latinx", "No Selection", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "Asian", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "Hispanic/Latinx", 
"Other", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", "No Selection", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "Black/African American", 
"No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "Asian", "Multiple", "White/Caucasian", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "No Selection", "No Selection", 
"Black/African American", "No Selection", "No Selection", "No Selection", 
"White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", "Other", "Black/African American", 
"No Selection", "Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "Black/African American", "No Selection", "No Selection", 
"No Selection", "Black/African American", "Multiple", "Black/African American", 
"Hispanic/Latinx", "Black/African American", "Asian", "Multiple", 
"White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "Asian", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"No Selection", "Black/African American", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "No Selection", 
"Black/African American", "No Selection", "Other", "No Selection", 
"No Selection", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", 
"White/Caucasian", "Other", "White/Caucasian", "White/Caucasian", 
"No Selection", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", "No Selection", 
"White/Caucasian", "Black/African American", "Black/African American", 
"Black/African American", "Other", "No Selection", "White/Caucasian", 
"Black/African American", "No Selection", "No Selection")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-140L))
```

Comment: You can use `table` i.e. `table(df)`

Comment: Could you please share your bigger dataset using 'dput(dataset)'?

Comment: Yes (edits above)! Thank you for including the dput command. I'm new to using stackoverflow and am still working through how best to share information.

Answer (score 1):

To make clear what @akrun said in the comments, you can use this code:

```
df <- structure(list('Student_Ethnicity' = c("White", "Black", "White", "Asian", "Black"), 
                     'Drawing_Ethnicity' = c("White", "Asian", "Black", "No Selection", "Asian")), 
                row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

table(df)
```

Output:

```
                 Drawing_Ethnicity
Student_Ethnicity Asian Black No Selection White
            Asian     0     0            1     0
            Black     2     0            0     0
            White     0     1            0     1
```

For your bigger dataset you can use the following code to make a count table of the student ethnicity:

```
table(df$Predict_DAS.Student_Ethnicity)
```

Output:

```
  American Indian or Alaskan Native                               Asian              Black/African American 
                                  6                                   5                                  33 
                    Hispanic/Latinx                            Multiple Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander 
                                 14                                  11                                   4 
                       No Selection                               Other                     White/Caucasian 
                                  7                                   9                                  51
```

As you can see, it gives the counts per ethnicity.

Comment: When I did this with my larger data set it created a column for student_ethnicity, a column for drawing_ethnicity, and then a column for frequencies. It tabulated correctly in the frequency column. I'm working to plug these into a chi-squared analysis so I need the normal table format. Any ideas why it would have done that?

Comment: @Randi, could you share a larger data then?

Comment: yes! I have added it as an edit to the original question!

Comment: @Randi, I added some code for your bigger dataset.

Comment: is there a way to tabulate which ethnicity is related to which ethnicity (in the form of the previously outputted table)?